# Java Conditional Operator not returning correct value

Tags: java, if-statement, operators

I've a situation where i need to set values of one variable

The Code is

`employee.setType(!checkEmpty(e.getType()) ? propertyBean.getString(e.getType()) : "");`

Here, the `type` variable is a `String` and `checkEmpty(String s)` returns true if string is `null` or `""`.

`propertyBean.getString()` is used to get key from a properties file using

```
ResourceBundle propertyBean= ResourceBundle.getBundle("FileName");
```

Code for checkEmpty()

```
public static boolean checkEmpty(String val) {
    return (val == null || val.trim().equals(""));
}
```

Now the value of e.getType is NULL and this code is giving me an error

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle    java.util.PropertyResourceBundle
```

Ideally it should not have given me this error. To fix this, i changed the condition to

```
employee.setType(checkEmpty(e.getType()) ? "" : propertyBean.getString(e.getType()));
```

It is working fine now. Can someone please explain me why the first one did not work.

Thanks

Comment: `checkEmpty(String s) returns true if string is null or ""` ... it returns `true` _or_ an empty string?  This sounds off to me, can you include the code for `checkEmpty()` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Done.

Comment: What does employee.setType method do. This is being called in the condition check.

Comment: @SripriyaV - It just sets the type of an employee. 'e.type' stores the type  code and' employee.type' will store the description.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Missed checking the paranthesis.

Comment: How is your method `propertyBean.getKey(e.getType())` implemented? In your post `propertyBean` it's of type `java.util.ResourceBundle`. But this has no `getKey(...)` method. Could you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the observed behaviour.

Comment: @SubOptimal - Sorry ,it is a typo, it actually uses ResourceBundle getString() method only

Comment: Probably type is a string "NULL" instead of a null reference?
`!checkEmpty(null)? "yes" : "no"` always returns "no" as for me

Comment: I agree with @Normal and believe the full exception message reads `java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key NULL`. Where the `NULL` stays for the value you pass to `propertyBean.getString("NULL")`.

Comment: It does not read this way. Even i thought of it but it says
`Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key  `
That means it is taking blank value